# saving data to mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am having an issue trying to save data to MongoDB.

I first run this python program:

```
import pymongo
import sys

def main():
    connection = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://localhost", safe = True) 

    db = connection.m101
    people = db.people

    person = {'name':'Barack Obama', 'role':'president'}
    people.insert(person)
```

but then, when i try to retrieve the data from the mongoshell:

```
> use m101
```

switched to db m101

```
 > db.people.find()
```

returns nothing! I'm not sure what is going on. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not working because `main()` is never called.

Adding

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

will execute your defined `main` function when executed.

Comment: To clarify: Python will execute the outermost scope (no indent level) when executing the file directly; as written in the question, the script just defines `main` without calling it.

The `__name__ == '__main__'` predicate ensures that `main` is only executed if the script is executed directly (i.e. `python my_main.py` from a console); `main` will _not_ be executed if this script is imported. Whether this is the desired behavior depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing your `main()` function so nothing was ever executed.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple solution

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import json
import datetime
import urllib, json
from flask import jsonify
from bson.json_util import dumps

@app.route("/saveBookings", methods=['POST'])
def saveBookings():
    posts = mongo.db.bookings

    post = {"meetingRoom_name": "kriti_jio",
          "personName": "honey",
         "meetingRoom_location": "kannauj",
         "book_start_time": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
    post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id
    return  jsonify(status="done",id=dumps(post_id),action="Data saved Succesfully",error="false");
```